# newline lost with python code generated with minted in a pdf

Tags: texstudio, minted, python

I'm trying to insert `python3` code in a Latex document with `Texstudio``

I have the following code:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{Python}
import numpy as np
x = 2
print("hello world") 
print("hello world again") 
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I can generate a pdf, the problem is that when I try to copy the code from the pdf to the text editor, the `newline` command before the 2 last line is lost and I get the following code and it gives me an understandable syntax error if I try to run the code:

```
import numpy as np
x=2
print("hello world") print("hello world again")
```

Comment: copy & paste of code from a pdf is unreliable and for python (where spaces and indents matter) more or less useless. If you want to offer code, embed/attach it as file in the pdf.

Comment: thank you for your answer @UlrikeFischer. Well too bad! What do you mean with embed/attach: write the url for a github repo (which I don't have for this document for example). The idea would be to have all the information (theory with code) in one single document

Comment: Check the attachfile2 and embedfile packages.